# Cut String out of String / 3 Parts

Tags: php, string, split, cut

I wan't to cut my string like this

```html
a = "dog [hidden] cat [/hidden] fox"


$1 = "dog ";
$2 = " fox";
$hidden = " cat ";
```

Im looking for a smooth way to do it! Thank you guys!

Comment: Is `[hidden]` always surrounded by spaces?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This was really fun to mess with.

First thing first, we need to break down the string into meaningful parts:

```
php > var_dump(preg_split('/(\[hidden\])|(\[\/hidden\])/', 'dog [hidden] cat [/hidden] fox', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "dog "
  [1]=>
  string(8) "[hidden]"
  [2]=>
  string(5) " cat "
  [3]=>
  string(9) "[/hidden]"
  [4]=>
  string(4) " fox"
}
```

From here we, want to find the when the `[hidden]` starts and where it ends. This will be done by searching the array to find their indexes. However, since there is only the hidden tag and no other tags in your example, we know that the value immediately after `[hidden]` is `$hidden`, everything before it is `$before` and the index of `hidden` plus 2 is everything after it (`$after`).

```
$hidden_start_index = array_search ("[hidden]", $my_array);
$before = my_array[hidden_start_index-1];
$after = my_array[hidden_start_index+2];
$hidden = my_array[hidden_start_index+1];
```

Putting it all together, you get this:

```
// Declare string
$a = 'dog [hidden] cat [/hidden] fox';
// Break it down
$my_array = preg_split('/(\[hidden\])|(\[\/hidden\])/', $a, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
// Find hidden index
$hidden_start_index = array_search ("[hidden]", $my_array);

// Find values
$before = $my_array[$hidden_start_index-1]; // dog
$after = $my_array[$hidden_start_index+2]; // cat
$hidden = $my_array[$hidden_start_index+1]; // fox
```

You may want something more complex, but the foundation of logic is here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I propose you:

```
<?PHP

$text = "dog [hidden] cat [/hidden] fox";

// find the "hidden" words between the tags
preg_match_all("/\[hidden\] ?(.*?) ?\[\/hidden\]/", $text, $hidden);
print_r($hidden[1]);

// find the "visible" words using a diff
$all = array_map("trim",preg_split("/\[\/?hidden\]/", $text));
$visible = array_values(array_diff($all, $hidden[1]));
print_r($visible);

?>
```

Output:

```
HIDDEN WORDS:

Array
(
    [0] => cat
)

VISIBLE WORDS:

Array
(
    [0] => dog
    [1] => fox
)
```

You can try a demo visiting [this link](https://eval.in/928167).